# Validation issue for Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a task based on the user input. So far it's working but when the user insert the invalid number for option 2, it still prints error message to try again but also prints out the calculations for it. I have the image and code listed below.

What would be the best way to when the user enters an invalid number for option 3 to not print out the numbers. Appreciate the help!

[image]

```
# # #  Program asks the user to choose options below to start with option selections
    print('\nChoose one of the following options below:')
    options=int(input(' 1. Display "10 Ways to Cut 500 Calories" Guideline. \n 2. Generate next semester weight table. \n 3. Quit \nEnter Option: '))

    # # # Section for "10 Ways to Cut 500 Calories"
    if options == 1 :
        print('Try these 10 ways to cut 500 calories every day.')
        print('* Swap your snack. ')
        print('* Cut one high-calorie treat.')
        print('* Do not drink your calories.')
        print('* Make low calorie substitutions.')
        print('* Ask for doggie bag.')
        print('* Just say "no" to fried food.')
        print('* Build a thinner pizza.')
        print('* Use a smaller plate.')
        print('* Avoid alcohol.')
        print('* Source: US National Library of Medicine.')
        
        continue
        
    # # # Section to generate next semester weight table 
    elif options == 2 :
        weight=int(input("Please enter starting weight in pounds (>=100)"))
        print('----------------------------------')
        print('Month  Weight ')
        print('----------------------------------')

        # # # Weight table calculations for the table 
        for i in range(0,7):
            weight=weight-4   
            print(i,'   ',weight,' lbs')

            # # # If user puts weight less than <100 pound, they will get an invalid message and try again
            if weight<100 :
                print('Error . . . Try Again', options)
                continue


    # # # Section to generate "Good Bye" message for the user when they decide to exit 
    elif option3 == 3 :
        print('\nGood Bye . . .')
```

Comment: Well, that's what your program does. It prints the calculated weight and **then** it checks if weight is less than 100. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Yes, and I'll check out the link you have. Thank you and have a good one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about the logic you state in your description and code. I believe the `if` should be outside the `for` loop and probably replace it with a `while`. So you ensure to get a specefic answer, else the "Try again" message will keep showing up. These are the changes I suggest.

```
    # # # Section to generate next semester weight table 
    elif options == 2 :
         weight = int(input("Please enter starting weight in pounds(>=100)"))
        while weight < 100:
           print("Error... try again")
           weight = int(input("Please enter starting weight in pounds (>=100)"))
        print('Month  Weight ')
        print('----------------------------------')
        # # # Weight table calculations for the table 
        for i in range(0,7):
            weight=weight-4   
            print(i,'   ',weight,' lbs')
```

Sorry for the poor formatting. I am writing from my phone

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, I used the while and worked out. Still new to this and I  appreciate you taking the time to help and explaining it. Have a good week ahead!

Comment: Glad it was of help to you! Feel free to accept the answer (with the tick on the left). This will mark your question as answered and reward with some points too! Cheers and let me know if there's any other question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to infinitely ask the user to input valid value.

```
# # # Section to generate next semester weight table 
elif options == 2 :
    # # # If user puts weight less than <100 pound, they will get an invalid message and try again
    while True:
        weight=int(input("Please enter starting weight in pounds (>=100)"))
        if weight >= 100:
            break  # stop asking when input is valid, get out of while loop
        print('Error . . . Try Again')

    print('----------------------------------')
    print('Month  Weight ')
    print('----------------------------------')

    # # # Weight table calculations for the table 
    for i in range(0,7):
        weight=weight-4   
        print(i,'   ',weight,' lbs')
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you as well for taking the time to answer. I'll add this to my study notes to review. Have a good week ahead!